# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 668: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python-3.x

I downloaded file and file is OK in excel, but in notepad it's  format is wrong

I spent a lot of time, but can't solve error

Link to file https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TDh81zdOggOexdaTxeiGz7r7jSkVqLEG

**My code:**

```
#to support encodings
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import codecs

path = "badcode.xlsx"

#read input file
with codecs.open(path, 'r', encoding = 'cp1251') as file:
  lines = file.read()

#write output file
with codecs.open(path, 'w', encoding = 'utf8') as file:
  file.write(lines)
```

I have error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 668: character maps to

**What I did**:

```
path = "badcode.xlsx"
with open(path) as f:
    print(f)
```

Returns

> <_io.TextIOWrapper name='badcode.xlsx' mode='r' encoding='cp1251'>

Comment: The algorithm determining the codepage got it wrong. This must be [cp1252](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) instead (a code page commonly used by Office products).

Comment: @usr2564301 I tried cp1252, but received error "UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 16: character maps to <undefined>"

Comment: According to my link, that code indeed is not valid for cp1252 – similar to how `98` is not valid for cp1251. If you have no idea whether this is an English (or a nearby European language), or possibly Greek, Cyrillic, Hebrew, or other encoding, you can always try `latin-1`. That's a unique encoding in that it maps straight to Unicode codes 0000 to 00FF.

Comment: @usr2564301 source language is Ispanol (mexican site https://go.heb2b.com.mx/HEBusiness/Preferencias) and I am from Russia. How this information can help me?

Comment: @usr2564301 Could you please elaborate your solution?

Comment: Okay, I now see what you *think* you were doing. **You cannot open an XLSX file as if it's plain text.** That is the root cause of **all** of your problems with this file. (For example: character encoding? opening it in Notepad?) You need the original software (Excel itself) or a dedicated library to read binary XLSX files, not a simple 'encoding'.

Comment: Just for the record: my proposed `latin-1` encoding indeed works on your file: `with codecs.open(path, 'r', encoding = 'latin-1') as file: lines = file.read() print (lines)` does not yield DecodeError anymore. That is because – as I said above – all bytes map directly to valid Unicode characters. But it's of no use for you because this is for *text files*, not *binaries*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This code helps me**

```
    import pandas as pd

    sourceFileName = "badcode.xlsx"
    df = pd.read_excel (sourceFileName)
```